# Jquery: Append a Class on hover of a div and remove when not hover

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass, removeclass, jquery-hover

I want to append a class to a div on hover of that div and remove that class when its not on hover. And when I hover on another div, again this class should be appended and removed when its not  on hover. Someone say me how to do it in jquery......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#id').hover(function(){
        $('#id2').toggleClass('classname');
    });
});
```

Or try this, because `hover` is [no longer supported in jquery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#quot-hover-quot-pseudo-event)

```
$(function(){
    $('#id').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
        $('#id2').toggleClass('classname');
    });
});
```

Comment: I would like to point out, even if it's a year later, that jQuery does support the hover element, for anyone looking this up. Still, the toggleClass is a nice idea.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use `addClass` and `removeClass` functions in jquery

**Refer Following Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('#secID, #thID').hover(function(){     
        $('#oneID').addClass('red');    
    },     
    function(){    
        $('#oneID').removeClass('red');     
    });
});
```

Can refer following links:

**AddClass:** http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

**RemoveClass:** http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Hope Its Helpful.